# A doubt on Krull's Principal Ideal Theorem Proof

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian, krull-dimension

Sorry if it is a dumb question but i'm studying the proof of Krull's PIT from [this pdf](http://www2.gsu.edu/~matfxe/commalglectures/lect14.pdf) and i don't understand why the author uses in his proof the ideals $P^{(n)}=P^nR_P\cap R$ instead of the simpler $P^n$. It seems to me that it should work the same. Moreover, in an integral domain aren't $P^{(n)}$ and $P^n$ the same ideal?

Comment: Not that i care too much about internet points, but there is a reason why my question has been downvoted? It's in some way against the rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ideals $P^{(n)}$ are $P$-primary (why?), while $P^n$ is not necessarily.

This also leads to an answer to the question if they coincide in an integral domain: from the [Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primary_ideal#Examples_and_properties) dedicated to the primary ideals we learn that there are prime ideals in integral domains, e.g. $R=K[X,Y,Z]/(XY-Z^2)$ and $P=(x,z)$ such that $P^2$ is not primary. In particular, $P^2\ne P^{(2)}$.

Comment: The symbolic powers are $P$-primary. But is this their only property that is used in the proof concerned by the question ? Explicitly: Suppose $Q$ is $P$-primary and we have $xy \in Q, x \not\in P$. Does it follow $y \in Q$ ? To my understanding we could only say that a power of $y$ lies in $Q$. But this wouldn't suffice in the proof in question.

Comment: The point is: I don't think your answer actually answers the question because it is missing an important property of $P^{(t)}$ that is used in the proof.

Comment: "Suppose Q is P-primary and we have xy∈Q, x∉P. Does it follow y∈Q ?" Yes. (Read carefully the definition of primary ideals.)

Comment: @tj_ The point is: you don't know the definition of primary ideals. (Helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264879/primary-ideals-confusion-with-definition.)

Comment: @ user26857: If one gives an answer and someone says, I don't understand this part, one should be able to give an exact proof of this part. This is how mathematics works.

Comment: @tj_ The point is that you haven't asked me anything. You simply claimed that the primaryness is not enough and my answer missed an important property of symbolic powers which yours pointed out.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is two-fold:

(1) Why is $P^{(n)}$ used in the proof and not $P^n$ ?

(2) Is $P^{(n)}=P^n$ in domains ?

**Answers:**

(2) No. Eisenbud (3.9.1 in his commutative alg. book) figured out a counter-example: Let $R=k[x_{ij}\mid 1 \le i,j\le 3]$ be a polynomial ring over a field and let $d = \det(x_{ij})\in R$ be the generic determinat. Then there is a prime ideal $P \subseteq R$ with $d \in P^{(2)}$ but $d \not\in P^2$.

(1) The proof of Th. 1.2 in the linked pdf uses in an essential way following property of $P^{(t)}$:

> If $xr\in P^{(t)}$ and $x \not\in P$ then $r \in P^{(t)}$.

In general, $P^t$ doesn't have this property. The following example is taken from Atiyah-MacDonald: Let $R=k[X,Y,Z]/(XY-Z^2)$ and denote by $x,x,z$ the images of $X,Z,Z$ in $R$. Then $P=(x,z)$ is prime, $xy=z^2\in P^2, y \not\in P$, but $x\not\in P^2$.

BTW: I don't think it's a dumb question. Scrutinizing proofs from literature is quite helpful to get a thorough understanding of the stuff!

Comment: Thanks. For some reason i thought that $P^n$ was P-primary, but both counter-example are interesting on their own

Comment: @karmalu As far as I can see this answer doesn't use the word "primary".

Comment: Well, the property highlighted in blue derives from $P^{(n)}$ being P-primary. So if $P^n$ was P-primary you could have used them instead with no problem.