# Definition of a primary ideal in a commutative ring

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

The definition of a primary ideal $P$ is :
$ x y\in P $implies either $x \in P $or $y^n \in P$ for some$ n > 0$.

My question is, why is it $x$ and not $x^n$ in the definition? Replacing $x$ by $x^n$ doesn't make a difference, does it?

Comment: I feel like the accepted answer here might be of some help -- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264879/primary-ideals-confusion-with-definition

Comment: If you are bothered by the "lack of symmetry" in this definition of primary ideals, then use this one: $Q$ is primary iff every zerodivisor in $R/Q$ is nilpotent. (Let $P$ stand for prime ideals!)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/728363/29335 also