# Is it true that an ideal is primary iff its radical is prime?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Is it true that an ideal $I$ in a commutative ring is primary iff $Rad(I)$ is prime?

If not, what are some nice counterexamples?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a simple example with $I$ not primary such that $Rad(I)$ is prime. Consider the ideal $(y^2,xy)\subset K[x,y]$. The radical of this ideal is $(y)$, i.e., it is prime.

At the same time, clearly $x\cdot y\in I$. Also, $y\notin I$. Nevertheless $x^n\notin I$ for any $n$. Hence $I$ is not primary!

*Comment.* As user26857 noted in a remark, one can even construct a prime ideal $p$ such that $p^2$ is not primary, though the example is a bit more complicated:

[Is each power of a prime ideal a primary ideal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/93478/is-each-power-of-a-prime-ideal-a-primary-ideal?rq=1)

Comment: @agleaner This example seems to be inordinately useful. I've seen it used and used it myself a couple different times over the past year!

Comment: If $xy\in I \subseteq \sqrt{I}$ and $\sqrt{I}=P$ is prime, then $x\in P$ or $y\in P$. Thus $x^n \in I$ or $y^m\in I$. Which fact am I missing here?